# Is bilinear pairing reversible?

Tags: elliptic-curves, pairings

Given $e(a,b)$ as known, can I get the value of $a$ or $b$?

Comment: HINT: Let $k$ be any integer modulo the group order and let $c=k\cdot a$ and $d=k^{-1}\cdot b$. What is $e(c,d)$?

Comment: Or, do you mean "if I know (for example) $e(a, b)$ and $a$, can I get the value of $b$?